# I was initially using Environment objects in my app to manage state in my application, but now need coreData. Should i drop the environment object?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am quite confused how to integrate CoreData with my application. I am using environment objects as my model to manage state, however this does not hold state long term and need information to be saved when the application is closed. Therefore I was told to use CoreData, nonetheless I have now setup my first Entity and do not know how to integrate it into my application.

Is there any way of setting environment objects to the entities of my CoreData andupdate the coreData once the application closes etc.

To give some context I have environment objects which change when a user input's some information, and use that environment object to store data in my CoreData. How do I then change my environment object on every view to match those of my CoreData (is it in some initialiser?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Stanford iOS course [episode 12](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yOhyOpXvaec).

A great example of how to add CoreData to an existing app.

The to keep your views updated with the contents of the CoreData database use the @FetchedResults property wrapper. ([hackingwithswift example](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-fetchrequest-property-wrapper))

Note: Use the @StateObject property wrapper instead of @ObservableObject in your views. The Stanford instructor is using an old version of SwiftUI. The recommended implementation is now to use @StateObject.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Environment Object in that case I guess, since the CoreData information can be used directly, and it updates your view too.

You first need to add the persistenceControler of CoreData in the Environment:

```
@main
struct YourApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
    
    @StateObject var otherEnvironmentStuff: OtherEnvironmentStuff = OtherEnvironmentStuff()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
                .environmentObject(otherEnvironmentStuff)
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can use CoreData directly in all views, and add data, that will directly be used in the views:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: EntityClassName.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \EntityClassName.name, ascending: false)],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "someAttributeName == %@", NSNumber(value: false)),
        animation: .default)
    private var myEntities: FetchedResults<EntityClassName>
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Do Whatever you want with the CoreData data...")
    }

    func addValue() {
        let newEntity: EntityClassName = EntityClassName(context: viewContext)
        newEntity.someAttributeName = someValueToSet
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't need the predicate or sortDescriptors, just remove them.

If you don't have a PersistanceController, just create a new Xcode Porject for SwiftUI with CoreData, there Xcode will create you one and you can just copy it into your current Project.